# Maximization using Lagrange multiplier when one constraint is homogenous

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I have $a,b,c\ge-1$. If I wish to maximize the function $f(a,b,c)=a+b+c$ subject to the constraint $g(a,b,c)=a^5+b^5+c^5=0$, how do I proceed?

The usual way of partially differentiating $f(a,b,c)+\lambda g(a,b,c)$ and equating to zero gives me no critical points. What should do to find the critical points? How is the condition $a,b,c\ge-1$ to be used here? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Comment: Alternatively, you may let $a = x^2 - 1, b = y^2 - 1, c = z^2 - 1$. Then deal with $f(a,b,c)+\lambda g(a,b,c)$.